# Remove line breaks on lines ending with commas

Tags: python, bash, csv, kml

The shell script I wrote to generate the CSV file has some issues with line breaks because I used both python and bash. How do I turn this(filename: data.csv):

```
12:30:42, 
-114.000000, 33.000000, 
0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, 
-114.100000, 33.000000, 
0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

into this (filename: data.csv):

```
12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

using bash - removing some of the line breaks but not all.

Answer (score 1):

Through python,

```
import re
foo = open('file').read()
file = re.sub(r'(, *)\n', r'\1', foo)
print(file, end='')
```

The above code remove the newline character from the lines which ends with comma followed by zero or more spaces.

```
$ python3 file.py
12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

Through Perl,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(, *)\n/\1/g' file
12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

Add `-i` parameter to save the changes made .

```
perl -i -00pe 's/(, *)\n/\1/g' file
```

`-00` option turns paragraph slurp mode on. `(, *)\n` captures the last comma along with the spaces and stores it into a group for later reference. Replacing the matched characters with the characters inside group 1 resulted in removing `\n` characters on those lines which ends with `,` . Thus giving you the desired output.

From perldoc perlrun:

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/ ) as an octal or hexadecimal
>   number. If there are no digits, the null character is the separator.
>   Other switches may precede or follow the digits. For example, if you
>   have a version of find which can print filenames terminated by the
>   null character.
>
> ...
>
> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.
>   Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by
>   convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

A solution using awk would be like

```
$ awk '!(NR%3){print line$0; line=""; next} {line=line$0}' data.csv
12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk '{$0=l=(a?$0:l$0)}a=!(NR%3)' file
```

#### Output

```
12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = open("filename").read()
data = data.replace(",\n", ",")
open("filename", "w").write(data)
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs -n8 < infile

12:30:42, -114.000000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
12:31:42, -114.100000, 33.000000, 0.0, 765, 15, 42, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure Bash:

```
joined_line=
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    joined_line+=$line
    if [[ ! $line =~ ', '*$ ]] ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$joined_line"
        joined_line=
    fi
done <data.csv
```

This deletes the newlines on lines that end with a comma followed by zero or more space characters.  The question title suggests that the lines end with commas, but the examples have lines that end with a comma followed by a space.

I've omitted error handling for the cases where the last line ends in a comma or the last line is not terminated.